# How to traverse two columns and fill in another column at the same index with a string in R?

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a data frame with a column of strings that are the question body of a survey, then I have a separate data frame with those question bodies matched two a question number. I want to traverse the original data frame's column and check if the value matches any within the other data frame and if does I want to store the associated question number in a column in the original df. I am having a lot of trouble figuring this out, I have looked into using apply() or something like that but I can't quite get it. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please read the info about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269). This will make it much easier for others to help you.

Answer (score 0):

If df is the first dataframe and df2 the second and Q is the name of the question strings column, then:

```
library (dplyr) 
left_join(df1, df2, by=question_body) %>% select(-question_body)
```

Of course, it would be easier to give you an accurate answer if you provided some actual examples of your data structure.

Comment: Imagine we have df1 where it is a matrix with columns (question_id, question_body, participant_id) and each column has thousands of different rows. Then there is a much smaller data frame df2 that is a matrix with columns (question_number, question_body) and has the template of the original questionnaire and its responses. Now df1 is much larger and has many repetitions of the questions in df2, but I want to replace every instance of each question_body in df1 with the corresponding question_number from df2 if that makes sense.

Comment: It's really hard to "imagine" this. It would really be best if you'd provided a reproducible example.

Comment: Also, did you try my solution? It should work for what you're describing.